# Why innerHTML is not working? (while textContent is working)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement some examples from book and I cannot force this code with **innerHTML** to work (however **textContent** is working):

```
function checkLength(e, minLength) {      
  var el, elMsg;
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event();
  }  
  el=e.target || e.srcElement;
  elMsg =el.nextSibling;
  if (el.value.length<minLength) {
    //elMsg.textContent="Username must be " + minLength +" characters or more";    
      elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + '' characters or more'';    //why are you not working?????
  }     
}
```

...

full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaharo/wf7pzxft/18/)

***UPD.*** This mistake `"elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + '' characters or more'';` - was type error, sorry, guys, didn't noticed it

Comment: 1. `window.event` is not a function, 2. check your quotes (and the console of your browser)

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console. Look at the error message.

Comment: `.nextSibling` can return text nodes...

Comment: Probably an old book, textContent vs innerHTML and target vs srcElement and window.event (should be `window.event` not `window.event()`) vs the parameter sent into the function, assuming it was called by the event which fired it, plus an additional argument... and nextSibling could be including whitespace nodes (some browsers count them and some don't).... not a good example to learn from. Use a framework instead like jQuery, or angular, stuff like this is too fiddly and old... nowadays we use frameworks and let them worry about compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine as I see there are minor mistakes

```
elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + '' characters or more'';
```

This will genearte the syntax error so replace this with

```
 elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more';
```

you are using el.nextSibling that is wrong here you are to use

nextElementSibling so

replace

```
el.nextSibling
```

with

```
  el.nextElementSibling
```

now one more change

el.nextElementSibling will return next element from your username field, that is br tag in your case. You will have to put a element that has innerHTML propertie.
so replace

```
 <input type="text" id="username"/>
  <br/>
```

with

```
 <input type="text" id="username"/>
<span></span>
  <br/>
```

I hope this will help. If not then let me know and I will create a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: However, if I only leave <div> element after, this code is not working again - I mean if I just delete <br/> and additional suggested <span> or <p>. Can you just comment why?

Comment: No this would run perfect if you delete the br tag with additional span or p tag and leave your div. Please recheck your code I think you are doing some other mistake. I have created the jsfiddle. check it at https://jsfiddle.net/yy82vL32/

Answer (score 1):

ok I got the exact issue. your `elMsg =el.nextSibling;` is not an element it is `textNode`. on `textNode` `innerHTML` will not work.

Use below code, it will work.

`<input type="text" id="username"/><p></p>`

now your `elMsg` will be an element and you can use `innerHTML` on it.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf7pzxft/22/)

Also there is mistake in you code.

`elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + '' characters or more'';` should be
`elMsg.innerHTML='Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more'`;